# using the unorthodox `head {display: block}` to show text to user?

Tags: html, css, web-crawler, accessibility

The following example shows that by using CSS pseudo-elements you can render into the browser some viewable text that is "embedded" in a `<link>` or `<meta>` tag.

http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KporNg

This unusual technique will show text on a page, but the text doesn't seem to be selectable (in Chrome 49 at least) and my question is, **is text displayed in this way scrape-able?** … I mean:

1. How would a screen reader see this text?
2. How do spiders see this? ... like googlebot, for example? Do they?

Comment: #1) good question.. #2) spiders  can and do see the stuff in the head regardless of the css used on the page..

Comment: #1) they look like divs but they'er still just link/meta tags.. i don't believe a screen reader would notice them at all..

Comment: .. though you could try it..

Comment: Probably will depend on the screen reader, I don't think it's standardized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help answer your questions: http://www.sitepoint.com/is-generated-content-actually-content/

Based on the authors indication that:

> Generated content is not content at all, it’s presentation.

I would assume that since the content generated from the pseudo-element is part of the presentation, rather than the structure of the page, spiders/bots might not pick it up.

A quick example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emmguv2h/) and codebit:

```
.text:before  {
   content: "Hello World!";
}
```

also support this claim. If you inspect element and check the div, you will notice that ":before" is what is displayed in the html, rather than a direct output of the text from the pseudo-element (i.e: "Hello World!"). Since most bots aren't scanning through the stylesheets, it's likely that it won't be picked up.

Regarding Screen Readers, I believe that it depends on the type of reader and what it's set to interpret. Here is an interesting link from a popular reader called WebAim that appears to interpret part of the CSS as well: http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/
The only way to be sure is to test it out for yourself and see but like one commenter said above, I do not believe that screen readers are standardized.